# "svn update" doesn't show my updated files

Tags: subversion

Usually when I do an `svn update`, if files have changed, it will list those files along with the code changes.  However, on my current machine, it only shows the files changed by other people, but it doesn't show any file that I have changed myself.

How can I get the files I changed to show up with `svn update`?

Comment: What is your current machine ? distro/UNIX name please.

Comment: Do you mean `svn status` ?

Answer (score 1):

`svn update` will get you the latest code from svn. You can get changes made by others. If you make some changes you need to commit your code by using:

```
svn commit -m "message"
```

After that if you do `svn status` mentioned by @Aaron D. Marasco it will show modified files.